# Does bounded $L^2$-norm of $r$-th derivative imply bounded $L^2$-norm of $(r-1)$-th derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,\infty)$ such that $\int_0^1 \left|\frac{d^r}{d x^r} f(x)\right|^2 d x<\infty$ for some $1\leq r<\infty, r\in\mathbb{N}$. Does it hold that $\int_0^1 \left|\frac{d^{r-1}}{d x^{r-1}} f(x)\right|^2 d x<\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that $f$ is weakly differentiable $r$ times: set $g:=d^{r-1}f/dx^{r-1}$. Your assumption says that $g'\in L^2$. This implies by Sobolev embedding in dimension 1 that $g\in C^\alpha$ for some $\alpha$, in particular its  $L^2$.

If you mean $f$ is differentiable a.e. : no, let $C$ be the devil's staircase and consider $r=1$, $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1/C(x)^s & C(x)\neq 0 \\ 0 & C(x)=0\end{cases},$$ for some $s>0$. Then $f$ is constant $a.e.$ so $\int |f'|^2=0$, but by choosing $s$ correctly, I'm quite sure we can make $\int |f|^2 = \infty$.

Comment: I guess depending on your formulation of Sobolev embedding you will want to first use an extension theorem so that $f$ is compactly supported in some larger interval